# WFFM form is reloading and then redirecting to success page

Tags: wffm

We have a page that has 4 WFFM added. In one of the WFFM we have a success redirection another page.

The page are located as

Form Page: sitecore/content/SiteA/Page1

Success Page: sitecore/content/SiteA/SuccessPage

While clicking the button in the Page1, this page reloads and then redirects to SucessPage.

**Note**: We had also tried to enable the “IsAjax MVC Form Feild”. But unfortunately, the redirection is not taking place and no action is happening

Comment: What is your question/problem actually?

Comment: My question is, the form page is getting reloaded before redirecting to success page

Comment: I think that is standard behavior.. so what is your aim? You want to bypass this? And if so, why?

Comment: The Client doesn't want the page be reloaded and then navigate to success page. insted it should directly land to success page.